# node and typescript: property undefined when call route

Tags: node.js, typescript, mysql2

I'm decided to create a project without any ORM, only using mysql2 package + node(typescript), but I'm having a hard time figuring out this problem below:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userService' of undefined
```

This error appears when I tried to call the get route /api/user, but the service is being initialized on my controller class. I tested only the query and is returning everything as expected.

The main structure of my project will have a **repository** for database queries, a **service** for bussiness logic and a **controller** that will manage my routes.

user repository

```
import pool from './../config/db';

interface IUser {
    id: number,
    login: string,
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
}

class User {
    async getUsers (): Promise<Array<IUser>> {
        try {
            const [rows]: [Array<IUser>] = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM `clients`', []);
            return rows;
        } catch (err) {
            return err;
        }
    }
}

export default User;
```

UserService

```
import User from './../repository/user';

class UserService {
    private user;

    constructor () {
        this.user = new User();
    }

    getUsers () {
        return this.user.getUsers();
    }
}

export default UserService;
```

UserController

```
import UserService from '../services/user.service';
import express from 'express';

class UserController {
    public path = '/user';
    public router = express.Router();
    public userService;

    constructor () {
        this.userService = new UserService();
        this.initializeRoutes();
    }

    private initializeRoutes (): void {
        this.router.get(this.path, this.get);
    }

    get (req, res) {
        res.send(this.userService.getUsers());
    }
}

export default UserController;
```

And on my main file, I have this method that will call the routes:

```
  private routes (): void {
        const routes = [
            new UserController()
        ];

        routes.forEach((route) => {
            this.app.use('/api', route.router);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UserController, the `get` class method function is invoked by the router. So you should bind `get` function to the class instance mapper, so to `this` like that:

```
  constructor() {
    this.userService = new UserService();
    this.get = this.get.bind(this); // here you bind the function
    this.initializeRoutes();
  }
```

Comment: is there a way to avoid binding my methods? I'll have to do this with every method that instantiate another class?

Comment: i encourage you to reorganize your code, especially while creating your routes. I follow [this tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/@olatundegaruba/integration-testing-supertest-mocha-chai-6zbh6sefz) to create the layers. You may find it an old tutorial but it's really good. If you can't apply it to your project let's talk again. 
But other alternatives, you may you use arrow functions for class methods, or find a suitable babel plugin like [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-function-bind)